# Google Sheets - Automatically sort columns NEXT TO a Query so that the entire range re-orders together in real-time

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

[TEST sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1NXV7NxLXzMq9boqpzXPNWSBNpLa18A8KTSmOvNaAYcY/edit?usp=sharing)

Tab 1 = Registration data

Tab 2 = Attendance sheet

- A4 uses Query() to pull the appropriate student data into that sheet. As more students enroll, it will automatically re-sort based on School then Name.
- The actual attendance (Columns D:H) are manually entered.

Goal: I would like for the data in Columns D:H to automatically re-sort and follow the students as they re-sort....is this possible??!!

Comment: Hi, it is not possible since there is nothing that "ties" columns D:H with A:C.  Sheets may look like a database table, but they are all individual cells with no bindings.  In the registration sheet create a Key, then in another sheet, for each key add the values of columns D:H and then do a join query... kinda messy.  Perhaps just add all the data in the registration sheet.

Comment: @miturbe is correct the problem is that your data sets for the studen info and their registrations are on separate sheets. Using a key would be best if you only want to use formulae, or alternatively you could use an script solution to modify the attendance sheet when a new row entry is added in the registration sheet

Comment: Thank you miturbe and Rafa!